# MFA redirects to home

Tags: authentication

When trying to activate MFA a user who tries to login is

1. first 303 redirected to the page where he should go after login (setup in the login menu item)
2. then 307 redirected to home with this url `/component/users/captive?Itemid=120` which is home.

When setting the Login redirection to userprofile the MFA redirects correct with userprofile menu active.

When setting the Login redirection to an article linked in the main menu, the MFA redirects again to `/component/users/captive?Itemid=120`.

Is this hard coded? Where can i configure at which menuitem the user can enter his MFA credentials?